# Trouble With Building Live555 Media Server in VS2005

Tags: c++, build, compilation, visual-studio-2005, live555

This could be a very silly question to any long time C++, visual studio or live555 users but I am having problems building the live555 source code with visual studio 2005. I have found a good walk through guide for creating the projects manually because .mak files are no longer supported by newer versions of visual studio but am still having problems. It seems that visual studio cannot open the .hh files that come in the include folders and I have added to the header folders of each seperate project.

Is there something special you have to do to the compilier or a plugin for the IDE to allow VS2005 to open .hh header files?

This is the error I am getting:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file
>   'BasicUsageEnvironment.hh': No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that Visual studios cannot find the file, rather than it not being able to open that file type. If you right click on your project and go to

Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories

Now browse to the location of the .hh file and add it to the path. Visual studios should now be able to find the file in question. You may also have to add library paths to your solution. Please let me know if there are additional errors.